# Opencart. Слайд-шоу на весь экран

Tags: html, javascript

Делаю сайт, встала одна проблема - не могу сделать слайдер на всю ширину/высоту. Перепробовал все, что знаю. Подскажите, пожалуйста, решение задачи!

Comment: @iamkazimirov, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем вы видите проблему, как ее воспроизвести и т. д.

Comment: ширину чего - блока, экрана?